# Where should I place a "notify user" method in a Rails app (or any MVC app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

I have heard several views on MVC structure in a web application. Some people believe the model should be very small, and only contain ActiveRecord (or some other ORM) and small things like `validates` and `belongs_to`, so model's are only a couple lines long.

I personally think the model can play a larger role in apps. For example, I need to notify a user frequently throughout my app. The notifications can trigger from multiple controllers. They all send a notification to a user based on his or her notification settings, which is an object accessible through the user model.

I would like to make something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validations, relationships, etc

  def notify(event)
    notif = Notification.new
    notif.type = event.type
    notif.to = self.id
    # etc

    if notif.save
      # send the notification based on the settings
    end
  end
end
```

This would make it possible from any controller to use `@user.notify` to deliver messages to a user. This makes things really clean, but I realize there is some logic in my model. Not to mention the model makes another model.

Another approach I wouldn't mind is creating the notification and sending it through that object. So controllers could do `Notification.new(:to => @user.id, ...)` and then deliver the message via a `Notification.send`. This would also put some logic in the Notification object so it knows how to send itself. In fact, I might like this approach better than creating the notification object through the User model.

I don't mind these small bits of logic in the Model to make things convenient when sending messages from multiple controllers. Is this the best way to go about it? I suppose a more purist method is to include a NotificationHelper module in each controller that sends notifications?

edit: I've been reading a bit about "domain logic" in models. It seems like this is encouraged, and I suppose the `notify` or `send` methods are considered domain logic. Can any developer experienced in MVC comment on this?

Comment: Wouldn't having a User attribute called `notified` be easier? It seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: No... this is for sending notifications to users based on their settings (email, SMS, whatever). I am asking where to place the method that will actually send the notification. This method will save the notification in the database (`Notification` model, for history purposes), decide how to send it based on their preference, and then send it. There is no "notified" state for a user. I could send a user 1000 notifications.

Comment: Ah, I got it. In that case, what you had in mind sounds reasonable. Put the method in NotificationHelper and make the helper available at Application level. This way, you don't have to include the NotificationHelper in each controller individually.

Comment: That would work, but is actually what I am trying to avoid. I would rather put this logic in a model (either User or Notification). I am asking if that is an 'acceptable' solution. The reason for my questioning is that I have heard different outlooks on the role of the model in an MVC structure. I personally believe the model approach is better, but others (some who I work with) disagree. I would like the opinion from someone more experienced than just myself to (hopefully) back me up on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second approach you can use ActiveRecord::Observer

```
 class NotificationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   def after_create(notification)
       # some sending logic
   end
 end
```

But don't be shy extract small pieces of logic into their own classes, like

lib/user_notify.rb

```
 class UserNotify
   def event_trigger(user,event)
       # some logic
   end
 end
```

use naming concepts suitable for your system (maybe Notify.send_user_about_event, etc.)

Comment: This is fine and all, but doesn't necessarily answer my question. Also, why do you need an observer? Can't you just use `after_create` within the Notification model file?

Comment: for loose coupling, good explanation here [Use Observer](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/19-use-observer)

Comment: and adding explicit abstraction layer for better understanding your domain logic, and decoupling some things in small pieces for testing much easier and faster